# How to fix ' Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client' http header error in nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, express

I am facing this problem 'Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client', and have been reading but wouldn't figure out the solution to my code using the solutions to a similar question.

```
const signin = (req, res) => {
  if (USERS.length === 0){
   return res.status(404).send({
    'status':'error',
    'error': 'user not found! please use different credentials'
   }); 
  }else{
     // get user model and extract emaill and password
  USERS.forEach((elements, index, array) => {
    if (req.body.data.email != elements.email) {
      return res.status(404).send(`User witht the given email not found`);
    } else {
       // compare hashed passwords with user submitted password using bcrypt compare
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.data.password, USERS[index].password, (err, result) => {
        if (!result) {
          return res.status(400).send('wrong credentials password');
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send('login successful');
        }
      });
    }
  });
  }
};
```

Comment: Look at your forEach loop, you're sending each time a response... You're just allowed to send only one response...

Answer (score 1):

your problem mainly is that you are trying to send the response more than one time,
that because you are using `array.foreach` and this kind of loop, won't break with `return`, so it keeps looping until the last element, which makes the possibility of executing `res.status().send()` multiple times for the same request, what you can do is using `foreach(let user of Users)` and breaks if any condition met so you can change your code to be:

```
const signin = (req, res) => {


if (USERS.length === 0){
   res.status(404).send({
    'status':'error',
    'error': 'user not found! please use different credentials'
   });
       return ;


  }else{
     // get user model and extract emaill and password
  for(let elements of Users USERS){
    if (req.body.data.email != elements.email) {
      res.status(404).send(`User witht the given email not found`);
       break;
    } else {
       // compare hashed passwords with user submitted password using bcrypt compare
        bcrypt.compare(req.body.data.password, USERS[index].password, (err, result) => {
        if (!result) {
          res.status(400).send('wrong credentials password');
          return;
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('login successful');
            return;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  }
};
```

Make sure that I surround the curly braces right.

Comment: thanks. however, a problem (`unsysntatic break`) arises in using a break inside the bcrypt arrow function.

Comment: You can't use that break inside a function.
Also, because of the first `if` statement inside the for loop, if the first user in the users array does not have a matching email, then the response will be an error whereas it probably should continue searching. But that's really more of a problem with OP's original code.

Comment: sorry, I've edited my answer, hope that works for you, I wasn't paying attention to the bcrypt callback

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to send a response (`res.status`) multiple times, but that's not allowed.

You also have a problem in your algorithm that causes a `404` to be sent every time a user in your database's email doesn't matched the email supplied in the request.

What you should do is separate the find-user step and the password compare step. First try to [find a user in the USERS array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) by their email, and if successful, compare the plaintext password from the request to the hashed password in your database.

```js
const signin = (req, res) => {
  if (USERS.length === 0){
   return res.status(404).send({
    'status':'error',
    'error': 'user not found! please use different credentials'
   }); 
  }
  // find user by email
  const user = USERS.find((user) => {
    return req.body.data.email === user.email
  }
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(404).send(`User with the given email not found`);
  }
  // compare hashed passwords with user submitted password using bcrypt compare
  bcrypt.compare(req.body.data.password, user.password, (err, result) => {
    if (!result) {
      return res.status(400).send('wrong credentials password');
    }
    return res.status(200).send('login successful');
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. The only issue I avoided `array.find` method is that It can't be used for cases where I want to match multiple objects in the array.

Comment: For that you will want to use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 0):

```
const signin = (req, res) => {
  if (USERS.length === 0){
   return res.status(404).send({
    'status':'error',
    'error': 'user not found! please use different credentials'
   }); 
  }

     // get user model and extract emaill and password
  let user = undefined;
  USERS.forEach((elements, index, array) => {
    if (req.body.data.email === elements.email && user !== undefined) {
       user = USERS[index];
       break;
    }
  });

  if (user === undefined) {
      return res.status(404).send(`User witht the given email not found`);
  }

  bcrypt.compare(req.body.data.password, user.password, (err, result) => {
        if (!result) {
          return res.status(400).send('wrong credentials password');
        } else {
            return res.status(200).send('login successful');
        }
   });
};
```

Comment: I think having `break` inside that `forEach` will return a syntax error. If you just use [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) then this is pretty much the right answer.

Comment: @Khauri , I opted for `forEach` loop because it is the only way I know I can retrieve the index of the object in the array. Can we get the same with `array.find` method?

Comment: @Kose see my answer. You don't need the index for what you're doing, only the element itself, but for future reference [`array.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) will do just that.

Comment: With a few tweaks, this solution works. The clue I got from here is separating other computations from the loop and only keeping the main condition inside the loop.
Thanks all and @Khauri